# rake db:structure:dump fails postgresql no such file or directory pg_dump

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create structure.sql of existing schema. but getting same error while executing db:structure:dump

No such file or directory - pg_dump -i -s -x -O -f F:/Workspace/TestApp/db/structure.sql db_name

I tried deleting schema.rb and chnages schema format to :sql, But it did not work either.

How to deal with this?

Comment: What is your rails version pooja

Comment: It's 3.2.11. And, I am using windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue...

I just have to add postgres to PATH env variable, after that it worked..